# R studio: Customize the editor

Tags: rstudio

I want to only change the color of the numbers in my editor.  I want the numbers 1:100 to be another color than dark grey (see picture).

This is how my editor looks now:
[image: This is how my editor looks now.]

This is my current settings in appearance:
[image: This is my current settings in appearance.]

Comment: You can embed the images in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can, follow this [blog post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/make-rstudio-look-the-way-you-want-because-beauty-matters/).

Basically, under the RStudio IDE you have simply `html + css` code that formats the theme.

Once you select a theme, you can access it's `css` file and change what you need.

You need to find in the `css` file the lines that changes that particular element.

For example, this will change the font color for the strings in my theme:

```
.ace_string {
  color: #3AD900
}
```